# what's the differences between pthread and -pthread options in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads

#### Environment

ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0, cmake 3.5.1

### Question

1. target_link_libraries(promise pthread)
2. target_link_libraries(promise -pthread)
3. target_link_libraries(promise -lpthread)

What's the differences, which is better ?

---

#### Problem

promise.cpp

```
std::promise<int> pr;
auto fut = pr.get_future();
pr.set_value(10); // throw std::exception and terminate
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(promise promise.cpp)
target_link_libraries(promise pthread)
```

---

#### Solution

Modify CMakeLists.txt slightly.

```
add_executable(promise promise.cpp)
target_link_libraries(promise -pthread)
```

I found the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43928715/unknown-exception-from-stdpromise). But I don't know why ?

**But, the best solution is portable.**

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads)
target_link_libraries(promise Threads::Threads)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All calls are *generally* **wrong**. As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49769069/3440745) by @vre, you should use `find_package(Threads)` instead.

#### But all these calls are *effectively* the same!

Calls

```
target_link_libraries(promise pthread)
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(promise -lpthread)
```

are transformed into the *same linker's command line*: for parameters not starting with `-`, CMake will add `-l` automatically (from `target_link_libraries` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html)):

> **A plain library name**: The generated link line will ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. `foo` becomes `-lfoo` or `foo.lib`).

While calls

```
target_link_libraries(promise -lpthread)
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(promise -pthread)
```

are translated into different flags, *for linking* process these flags means the same.

Option `-pthread`, passed to `gcc`, *would* [add additional compile definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling). But parameters for `target_link_libraries` are not used for *compilation*.

---

#### Why using `find_package(Threads)` is correct

If one uses

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON) # Without this flag CMake may resort to just '-lpthread'
find_package(Threads)
```

a library **target** `Threads::Threads` is created, with additional compile and link options `-pthread` attached to it as an *interface*.

When use

```
target_link_libraries(promise Threads::Threads)
```

CMake automatically *propagates* interface compile and link options, thus `promise` target is both **compiled** and *linked* with `-pthread` option.

Comment: You should have tried it, but, CMake generates `-lpthread` option, I have no idea what happened.

Comment: Do you mean not `-lpthread` but `-pthread` option? CMake generates `-pthread` option for **link command** ("Linking C executable"), but not for *compile command* ("Building C object"). This is what my answer talks about.

Comment: I used `find_packages(Threads) target_link_libraries(promise Threads::Threads)`, then `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON ..`, `make promise` I found g++ used `-lpthread` not `-pthread` option. It's confusing.

Comment: Then please add `set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)` before the `find_package` call. This is why I linked to the FindThreads.cmake documentation.

Comment: I have updated the answer with *THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG* flag using.

Answer (score 1):

First, we can use `cmake -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON` to see the underlying commands of `make`.

`target_link_libraries(promise pthread)` and  `target_link_libraries(promise -lpthread)` will result the same link option: `-lpthread`, like:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/promise.dir/promise.cpp.o  -o promise -lpthread
```

However, `target_link_libraries(promise -pthread)` will give you `-pthread` option:

```
/usr/bin/c++   -std=c++11  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/promise.dir/promise.cpp.o  -o promise -pthread
```

The difference between `-pthread` and `-lpthread` is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling). In general, you should use `-pthread` and `target_link_libraries(promise -pthread)`.

btw, `clang` built binary seems ok with both options.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the modern CMake way by means of imported targets:

```
set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(Threads)
target_link_libraries(promise Threads::Threads)
```

This does not only add the library dependency, it also sets the compile option and works on almost all platforms. See the answers to the following post for further details: 
[Difference between -pthread and -pthreads for C/C++ on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286803/difference-between-pthread-and-pthreads-for-c-c-on-ubuntu-14-04)

And have a look into the fine documentation of FindThreads.cmake module:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/FindThreads.html